# In Struts2 if I set devMode to false then calls to high response time actions are retried after 60 seconds

Tags: java, apache, struts2, timeout

**UPDATE**

I have since found out that this is not a Struts2 issue, but the application server's. On production environments my tomcat instance is behind Apache & it retries a HTTP request if it is not responded to within 60 seconds. I can always increase this limit but for my purposes it is not a feasible solution, so I am planning to immediately return for high latency requests, generate a `requestToken` and do long polling for this token to see if a response has been generated yet.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am using Struts2 framework (version 2.2.3). Some actions of take 60+ seconds to resolve. In such cases when the `struts.devMode` is set to `false` i.e. the prod environment settings are set, struts2 initiates retries on the action with same parameters as before and the previous action is still running. This does not happen when the `struts.devMode` is set to `true`.

Just to reiterate this does **not** happen on local dev machine where `struts.devMode` is set to `true` and is not behind `apache`.

I was able to reproduce this very simply by pinging to this method from the browser (happens in both chrome, FF)

```
public String sleepForTime() {

    try {
        for (int ii=0; ii<sleepForSeconds; ii++) {
            System.out.println("\n\n\nSTART Sleeping iteration " + (ii+1));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("END Sleeping iteration " + (ii+1));
        }

    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I have set `sleepForSeconds` to be less than 60, everything works fine. But as soon as I set to anything above it starts one more request every 60 seconds. Is there a parameter I need to tweak to make this not happen?

Comment: How would S2 retry a browser request?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure, if its the browser that initates the retry. There is nothing in the app code that would on it's own make one more request if the current request is pending for more than 60 seconds.

Comment: There's nothing in Struts that magically "retries" an action, either. I find it *highly* likely there's a page reload, a rogue JS timer, a bizarre proxy, a strange filter or interceptor, etc. that is initiating a new request, if it's actually a new request.

Comment: I think you might be right. I changed the `struts.devmode` to `false` in my local machine and I am unable to reproduce the issue. This only happens on live servers which is behind `apache`.

Comment: This happened to me on BEA Weblogic AS, while debugging... after some time, it repeated the request, making me debugging parts of code that I'd already debugged. Usually, it is AS fault for this kind of things ;)

Comment: A bigger issue may be that you are making the browser wait for over 60 seconds. That's definitely not user friendly.

Comment: @StevenBenitez I agree. It is an AJAX call and the user is intimated immediately that this is going to take time just because of the nature of the operation.